# Get the right object as "this" in my reactor pattern callback

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, this, reactor

First of all I would like say it is the first time i'm working with a reactor pattern.
I've tried a bit of everything with the knowledge I have but without any succes. This is my script so far:

```
function Reactor(){
  this.events = {};
}

Reactor.prototype.registerEvent = function(eventName){
  this.events[eventName] = {name: eventName, callbacks: []};
};

Reactor.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(eventName, eventArgs){
  for(var i in this.events[eventName].callbacks) {
    this.events[eventName].callbacks[i](eventArgs);
  }
};

Reactor.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, callback){
    if(typeof(this.events[eventName]) == 'undefined') this.registerEvent(eventName);
    return this.events[eventName].callbacks.push(callback) - 1;
};
```

and to test the script I have this

```
var test = new Reactor();

test.addEventListener('ping', function() {
    console.log(this); //I want this to be the 'test' object
});

test.dispatchEvent('ping');
```

So I create a new reactor object, adds a eventlistener to it and then dispatch the event. **But in the callback function I want "this" to be the "test" object.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your methods with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to force a particular `this` value:

```
Reactor.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(eventName, eventArgs){
  for(var i in this.events[eventName].callbacks) {
    this.events[eventName].callbacks[i].apply(this, eventArgs);
  }
};
```

(assuming `eventArgs` is an array, the callback will be called with each element from the array passed as a separate argument)

Comment: Besides the ")" after the apply() it works perfectly! Thanks for the fast answer. Gonna read the docs for apply(), didn't know about that function :-)

Comment: Oops, sorry about the extra `)`. I fixed that, and added links to the docs for call and apply. They just differ in the way they pass arguments to the function you're calling.